# from new import classobj in Python 3.1

Tags: python

How can I change the given python 2.x statement to get it compiled on 3.1.

The code line that not works.

```
from new import classobj
```

The error is "There is no module new".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2.x `new.classobj` is the type of old-style types. There are no old-style types in Python 3.x. To port your code from Python 2.x to Python 3.x you first need to bring it up to the latest Python 2.x standards, and in that case it means stop using old-style classes and only use new-style classes.

So the answer is instead of `classobj` use `type`, but you'll need to upgrade the 2.x code to use `type` first and then look at porting to Python 3.x

BTW, See PEP 3108 for the list of modules removed in Python 3.x. In particular:

> new
>
> - Just a rebinding of names from the    'types' module.
> - Can also call type    built-in to get most types easily.
> - Docstring states the module is no    longer useful as of revision 27241
>     (2002-06-15).

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`type`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#type) function:

```
X = type('X', (object,), {'a': 1})
```

Comment: Posted on the wrong page? This has nothing to do with the question asked here.

Comment: No, it's a good answer but possibly too telegraphic to be clear. Also `type` is a type rather than a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a package, you need to change it to a relative import:

```
from .new import classobj
```

Comment: I wasn't aware but 'new' is actually a builtin module in python version prior to 3.0. In Python 3.0 it has been removed.